# Що означає слово "клебаня"?

Tags: вживання-слів, діалектизми

Зустрів таку фразу "А в Івана була цурава **клебаня** на голові..." ("Як Іван ошукав корчмарів"). Однак, мені не вдалося знайти цього слова в Академічному тлумачному словнику, а на [цьому сайті](http://www.myslenedrevo.com.ua/uk/Sci/Linguistics/RareWords/K2.html) воно має значення "обійстя попа", що не може підходити по контексту.

Можливо ви знаєте чи зустрічали ще якісь значення цього слова?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У [Словнику української мови за ред Б. Грінченка](http://ukrlit.org/slovnyk/%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%8F) знаходимо:

> **Клебаня**:
>
> 1) Шляпа. Угор. Желех.
>
> 2) = Клепаня. Желех.

Оскільки є ще відсилання до другого варіанту, то ж шукаємо і це.
Тут Грінченко Б пише, що:

> **Клепаня**, ні, ж. = Капелюха. Гол. Од. 69. Шух. І. 137.

У [словнику-довіднику Жайворонка В. В.](http://ukrlit.org/slovnyk/zhaivoronok_znaky_ukrainskoi_etnokultury/%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%8F) читаємо:

> **клепа́ня** = клапа́ня — у Галичи­ні — зимова тепла шапка із черво­ного чи темно-синьою сукна, під­бита овчиною та облямована лися­чим хвостом.

У [СУМ-11](http://sum.in.ua/s/klapanja) немає слова "клебаня", однак є **клепаня**:

> Зимова тепла шапка, переважно з хутра.

Отже, *клебаня - це шапка*, яку носив на голові Іван.